# Spring Get all params from URL in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have in front end a form where the user selects the year and one or more months from a list of months. These params will be sent to Controller as Get Method.
 Given an URL like this:

```
..../{year}/{months}/excel/
```

Where months would be a variable list of the months selected, i.e [`01,02,10`].

How I receive all parameters in the Controller?
Here's my controller so far:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{year}/{months}/excel/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = EXCEL_FORMAT_HEADER)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView getRankingByYearExcel(@PathVariable("year") Integer year,
                                       @RequestParam Map<String, Object> months)
 {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it like this and worked, declaring `months` as array of Strings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{year}/excel/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = EXCEL_FORMAT_HEADER)
public @ResponseBody
ModelAndView getRankingByYearExcel(@PathVariable("year") Integer year,
                                   @RequestParam String[] months)
```

And in URL sent variable months as array of strings:

```
../2016/excel/?months=1,3,12
```

Thanks for guiding me in this direction

Answer (score 2):

I would change the  `@RequestParam Map<String, Object> months` to `@RequestParam String months` You can then split the months based on comma.

`String[] monthsList = months.split(",");`

The `monthsList` array will have all the user selected values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you bind all URI template variable to Map and use.

First of all, You need to change `@RequesetParam` to `@PathVariable`

example1:

```
@RequestMapping("{id}/messages/{msgId}")
public String handleRequest4 (@PathVariable Map<String, String> varsMap, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg", varsMap.toString());
    return "my-page";
}
```

example2:

```
@GetMapping("/request4/{name}/{age}/address/{city}/{country}")
@ResponseBody
public String handler(@PathVariable Map<String, String> params) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append("URL parameters - <br>");
   for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
      builder.append(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + "<br>");
   }
   return builder.toString();
}
```

For more information see [doc1](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-path-variable.html) or see [doc2](https://www.boraji.com/index.php/spring-4-mvc-pathvariable-annotation-example)